# python3 type hints: arg: dict, passing a str type doesn't raise a Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

the type of `cfg` should be `dict`.
I pass a string of `str` type to `cfg`, there is no Error raised? why

```
def __to_oxml_json_p__(cfg: dict, content: list, panel_cfg: dict = None):
    print(type(cfg), cfg)
```

outputs:

```
<class 'dict'> {'size': '14 pt', 'bold': True, 'font_family': 'xxx'}
<class 'str'> <<paragraph.basic>>
```

Why?

Comment: type hints in parameters will not check if the passed arguments is the type specified. Type hints are used so that IDEs can give you information about the type of function arguments and warn you if you call a function with wrong argument types.

Comment: Which type checker did you use? There are several, and whether or not something is considered a type error depends on the type system your type checker is implementing.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "type hinting"? Python doesn't have type hinting. Python itself has *type annotations*. A specific type checker for Python may or may not have type hinting, which brings me back to my other comment: what type checker and which type system are you using to check your types?